# Modifying element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
self.$el[0].options[0]
```

I get:

```
<option value="asd">asd</option>

self.$el[0].options[0].attr("selected","selected")
```

I get:

```
is not a function.
```

How do I modify the asd in js?
Is it because it's an html element?

Comment: Please show the complete select. For example If $el[0] is a select, `$el[0].value="asd";` will select the option - also `$el[0].selectedIndex=0` will select the first option

Comment: are you using jQuery or some other framework like Vue? If you're using pure js the function should be `.getAttribute` instead of `.attr`

Answer (score 2):

Your selector gets the DOM node. So, any jquery method won't get applied on DOM element. Instead you make it a  jquery object:

```
$(self.$el[0].options[0]).attr("selected","selected")
```

or you can use `setAttribute()` of DOM method:

```
self.$el[0].options[0].setAttribute("selected","selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use js API:

```js
document.getElementByTagNames['option'][0].setAtttribute('selected', 'selected')
```